# Segmentation fault while using a C module in a .so file

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault

I got a segmentation fault – probably caused by the long loop – while running my python script at the command line under Linux. I know exactly *where* the problem is, but I don't know *why*. I've tried some of the method I searched online, including this site, but I still cannot solve it. So, please help me – thank you in advance. Here follows some of the code:

#### 0

`analyzer.py`, where the program begins:

```
from classify import BayesClassifier
class Analyzer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.classify = BayesClassifier('/home/user/yakamoz/srcanalyzer/classification/training.tab')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Analyzer()
    # the following is a string of Chinese character, which, I am sure,
    # has no influence on the Segmentation fault, you can just suppose
    # it as a paragraph in English.

    text = "市委常委、纪委书记杨娟高度评价我县基层党风廉政建设：\
       务实创新成效显著作者：县纪委办公室发布时间：11月27日下午，\
       市委常委、纪委书记杨娟率领市纪委副书记蒋玉平、王友富，\
       市纪委常委、秘书长任斌，市纪委机关党委书记刘林建一行来我\
       县调研基层党风廉政建设。调研中，杨娟高度评价我县基层党风廉政建设，\
       认为工作务实创新，成效显著。县委书记陈朝先，县委副书记季代双，县委常委、\
       纪委书记韩忠明陪同调研。杨娟一行先后来到两河镇、西部花都、两江广场、\
       工业园区等地实地调研我县基层党风廉政建设，检阅我县“两化”互动、“三化”\
       联动发展成果。查阅相关资料在两河镇，杨娟认真听取了两河片区纪工委\
       日常工作开展情况的汇报，仔细翻阅了巡查工作日记和接访记录。杨娟指出，\
       设置乡镇片区纪工委是加强基层纪检组织建设的创新举措。\
       盐亭在全市率先设置、运行纪工委以来，在化解农村信访矛盾，理顺群众情绪，\
       强化基层办案工作等方面取得了明显成效。她要求，要总结提炼片区纪工委的经验，\
       进一步明确职能职责，在机构设置、人员配备、制度建设等方面进行探索实践，\
       为全市基层纪检组织建设提供有益经验借鉴。杨娟还饶有兴趣地参观了两河镇\
       的机关廉政文化建设"

    print str(a.classify.classify_text(text)[0])
```

#### 1

`classify.py`; this file is used by the `analyzer.py`, presented above:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from match import WordMatch
import cPickle
import math

class BayesClassifier:

    __trainingdata = {}                    
    __classifywordscount = {}
    __classifydoccount = {}

    def __init__(self, table_name):         
        self.trainingtable = cPickle.load(open(table_name, 'r'))  
        for x in self.trainingtable:
            self.train(x[1], x[0])  
        print 'training finished'
        self.matrix = self.get_matrix()         
        self.vector_count = len(self.matrix)
        self.doc_count = len(self.trainingtable)
        self.match = WordMatch(self.matrix)

    def get_matrix(self):                       
        matrix = {}
        for x in self.trainingtable:
            for k in x[0]:
                matrix[k] = 0
        return matrix

    def doc_to_vector(self, content):
        matrix = {word:value for (word, value) in self.match.find(content).items()}     
        return matrix        

    def train(self, cls, vector):
        if cls not in self.__trainingdata:
            self.__trainingdata[cls] = {}
        if cls not in self.__classifywordscount:
            self.__classifywordscount[cls] = 0
        if cls not in self.__classifydoccount:
            self.__classifydoccount[cls] = 0
        self.__classifydoccount[cls] += 1

        for word in vector.keys():
            self.__classifywordscount[cls] += vector[word]
            if word not in self.__trainingdata[cls]:
                self.__trainingdata[cls][word] = vector[word]
            else:
                self.__trainingdata[cls][word] += vector[word]
        

    def classify_text(self, content):
        t = -1 << 32
        res = "unknown classification"
        for cls in self.__trainingdata.keys():
            prob = self.__count(cls, self.doc_to_vector(content))
            if prob > t:
                res = cls
                t = prob
        return res, t
```

#### 2

`match.py`; this code is referenced by the `classify.py`

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import os
import re
import util.ahocorasick.x64 as ahocorasick
# util.ahocorasick.x64 is a folder where .so file locates

class WordMatch(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.__tree = ahocorasick.KeywordTree()
        if isinstance(arg, (list, dict)):
            for item in arg:
                if item:
                    self.__tree.add(item)
        elif isinstance(arg, basestring):
            if os.path.isfile(arg):
                fp = open(arg)
                for line in fp:
                    line = line.strip()
                    if line:
                        self.__tree.add(line)
                fp.close()
            else:
                print 'the path of the input file does not exist'
                return
        else:
            print 'parameter fault'
            return           
        self.__tree.make()

    def _findall(self, content):
        '''return the list of keywords that is found 
        '''
        hit_list = []
        if isinstance(content, basestring):
            for start, end in self.__tree.findall(content):
                if len(content[start:end]):
                    hit_list.append(content[start:end])
        else:
            print 'AC automation requires string '
        return hit_list

    def find(self, content):
        '''return those matched keywords and the corresponding count
        '''
        hit_list = self._findall(content)
        mydict = {}
        for item in hit_list:
            if item in mydict:
                mydict[item] += 1
            else:
                mydict[item] = 1
        return mydict
```

#### 3

`__init__.py`, under the folder `util.ahocorasick.x64`:

```
import _ahocorasick

__all__ = ['KeywordTree']


# A high level version of the keyword tree.  Most of the methods here
# are just delegated over to the underlying C KeywordTree 
#(in the .so file, which is not shown here).


class KeywordTree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__tree = _ahocorasick.KeywordTree();


    def add(self, s):
        return self.__tree.add(s)


    def make(self):
        return self.__tree.make()


    def zerostate(self):
        return self.__tree.zerostate()

    ##### !! I found this is where the segmentation fault occurs

    def __findall_helper(self, sourceBlock, allow_overlaps, search_function):
        """Helper function that captures the common logic behind the
        two findall methods."""
        startpos = 0
        startstate = self.zerostate()
        loop_times = 0            

        while True:
            #print spot_1
            match = search_function(sourceBlock, startpos, startstate)
            #print spot_2
            if not match:
                break
            yield match[0:2]
            startpos = match[1]
            if allow_overlaps: #which in my case is always false
                startstate = match[2]
            else:
                loop_times = loop_times + 1
                #print spot_3
                startstate = self.zerostate()
                #print spot_4
                #print loop_times

    def findall(self, sourceBlock, allow_overlaps=0):
        return self.__findall_helper(sourceBlock, allow_overlaps,self.__tree.search)
```

I am confused by the different result given: I've found that the problem lies in 3 `__init__.py` or rather, the `__findall_helper(self, sourceBlock, akkow_overlaps, search_function)`.

By uncommenting one of the following annotation:

```
#print spot_1
#print spot_2
#print spot_4
```

one can eliminate the segmentation fault and the loop is finite (the match can be `None`), but by uncommenting the `#print spot_3`, one can *not* (it seems like an infinite loop). Here comes my question:

Does the `print` statement has a side effect in python? I found only that there is a `print` statement in one of the three spots mentioned above (`spot_1` or `spot_2` or `spot_4`) can eliminate the fault. By the way, I found this by accident, there are no `print` at first.

#### 4

Here is the `backtrace` using `gdb`.

```
(gdb) r analyzer.py

Starting program: /usr/local/bin/python analyzer.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Detaching after fork from child process 11499.
training finished

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff178956d in ahocorasick_KeywordTree_search_helper (state=0x85c730, 
string=0x8967d4 "【中国环保在线 市场行情】“我国将在2016年启动全国碳市场。全国碳交    易市场的首批行业企业将由电力、冶金、有色、建材、化工5个传统制造业和航", <incomplete     sequence \347\251>..., n=140733193395828, startpos=118366835, 
out_start=0x7fffffffd468, out_end=0x7fffffffd460,       out_last_state=0x7fffffffd458) at aho-corasick.c:216
216 aho-corasick.c: No such file or directory.
in aho-corasick.c
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-    1.149.el6.x86_64

(gdb) bt

#0  0x00007ffff178956d in ahocorasick_KeywordTree_search_helper     (state=0x85c730, string=0x8967d4 "【中国环保在线 市场行情】“我国将在2016年启动全国碳市场。全国碳交     易市场的首批行业企业将由电力、冶金、有色、建材、化工5个传统制造业和航", <incomplete sequence \347\251>..., n=140733193395828, startpos=118366835, out_start=0x7fffffffd468, out_end=0x7fffffffd460,   out_last_state=0x7fffffffd458) at aho-corasick.c:216
#1  0x00007ffff178a2b1 in ahocorasick_KeywordTree_basesearch     (self=0x7ffff7f6c230, args=0x7ffff0ca1a50, kwargs=0x0, helper=0x7ffff1789525<ahocorasick_KeywordTree_search_helper>) at     py_wrapper.c:190
#2  0x00007ffff178a358 in ahocorasick_KeywordTree_search  (self=0x7ffff7f6c230, args=0x7ffff0ca1a50, kwargs=0x0) at py_wrapper.c:212
#3  0x00000000004a7103 in call_function (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4013
#4  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2666
#5  0x0000000000507e8d in gen_send_ex (gen=0x7904640, arg=0x0, exc=<value optimized out>) at Objects/genobject.c:84
#6  0x00000000004a25da in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2497
#7  0x00000000004a805b in fast_function (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4099
#8  call_function (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4034
#9  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2666
#10 0x00000000004a8bd7 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7ffff1ff54b0, globals=<value optimized out>, locals=<value optimized out>, args=<value optimized out>, argcount=3, kws=0x9984520, kwcount=0, defs=0x7ffff2016968, defcount=1, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3253
#11 0x00000000004a6dce in fast_function (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4109
#12 call_function (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4034
#13 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2666
#14 0x00000000004a805b in fast_function (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4099
#15 call_function (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:4034
#16 PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<value optimized out>, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2666
#17 0x00000000004a8bd7 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x7ffff7ec4130, globals=<value optimized out>, locals=<value optimized out>, args=<value optimized out>, argcount=0, kws=0x0, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3253
#18 0x00000000004a8ce2 in PyEval_EvalCode (co=<value optimized out>, globals=<value optimized out>, locals=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:667
#19 0x00000000004c91fe in run_mod (fp=0x880ee0, filename=0x7fffffffe30c "analyzer.py", start=<value optimized out>, globals=0x7fc140, locals=0x7fc140, closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffdea0) at Python/pythonrun.c:1346
#20 PyRun_FileExFlags (fp=0x880ee0, filename=0x7fffffffe30c "analyzer.py", start=<value optimized out>, globals=0x7fc140, locals=0x7fc140, closeit=1,flags=0x7fffffffdea0) at Python/pythonrun.c:1332
#21 0x00000000004c9414 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (fp=0x880ee0, filename=0x7fffffffe30c "analyzer.py", closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffdea0)at Python/pythonrun.c:936
#22 0x0000000000414a4f in Py_Main (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>) at Modules/main.c:599
#23 0x0000003fd281ed5d in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#24 0x0000000000413bc9 in _start ()
```

Comment: This is a huge amount of code, and I can't find anywhere obvious in there where you're accessing a `.so`. Can you give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: To answer your question: no, the 'print' statement has no side effect in python.

Comment: Can you use gdb to get a backtrace where exactly it segfaults? `gdb $(which python)` and type `r analyzer.py` and when it halts type `bt`

Comment: I apologize for the bad description, "import util.ahocorasick.x64 as ahocorasick" in the beginning of match.py is where exactly  the .so is import, it is where the AC automata algorithm is realized.@abarnert

Comment: thanks, but why the 'print' statement have the influence I've mentioned @gustafbstrom

Comment: Edit your post as you find issues useful to solve problem. And, as @abarnert said: try to simplify and narrow down your code. Your post is simply too long to follow.

Comment: I've tried it before and  was going to paste some screenshots of gdb debugging information. Unfortunately, I have not enough reputation. The r analyzer.py shows: "aho-corasick.c: No such file or directory. in aho-corasick.c", and the bt show much more, which is beyond my understand.@maxy

Comment: I appreciate your advice, I will try to narrow down my code. @gustafbstrom

Comment: gdb debugging information should be text, so there's no reason to post screenshots; text is more useful. Second, if you ever _do_ need to post screenshots and don't have the rep, upload them at your favorite image-sharing site and post links into your question (and maybe add a comment explaining that you didn't have the rep to do it any other way).

Comment: As for why `print` might have some influence… the most likely causes I can think of are (a) you've corrupted the stack or the heap and it's effectively random what causes it to eventually crash, or (b) some object from the C library is being over-decref'd and then used after it's freed, but calling the `__str__` method keeps it alive a little longer so you get lucky and its memory ends up not being overwritten as early and some operation that would have crashed doesn't, or (c) allocating the `str` just means a different dead object gets overwritten, one you happen not to access.

Comment: thank you for reminding, I've added the debugging information to the original. @abarnert

Comment: I think the reason is probably what you said in `(b)`, for the debugging information show that `aho-corasick.c: No such file or directory`. Then, how can I prove the conjecture and get the problem correct?

Comment: All that `aho-corasick.c: No such file or directory` means is that the debugger couldn't find the C source code to give you source-level tracebacks. It tells you nothing at all about why things segfaulted.

Comment: So you means that `aho-corasick.c: No such file or directory` has nothing to do with the segfault? I originally thought it is caused by the missing `.c` or somewhat else in the C library.@abarnert

Answer (score 0):

I see

```
  self.__tree = _ahocorasick.KeywordTree();
```

Then

```
self.__tree.zerostate()
```

and finally

```
return self.__findall_helper(sourceBlock, allow_overlaps,self.__tree.search_long)
```

So my guess is that the function `search_long` is invalidated when you do `__tree.zerostate()` so you get undefined behaviour which in some cases leads to a segfault. It's a lot of code and there's a opaque library so it's hard to tell for sure. Best thing is to go to the documentation and make sure you're using the library correctly.

The `print` is a red herring, and by allocating something just forces the crash to happen sooner.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, as you said, the `print` is a red herring. But the truth is that it does has an impact on the result (crash or not). If the funcion `self.__tree.search` is invalidated, the result should be segfault whether or not there is a `print` statement. but each time it exist, it works well, and crash on the contrary. Of that, I can be certain. @Sorin